# Security-Scoped Bookmarks for a directory

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsurl, appstore-sandbox, nsopenpanel

I need to give full read/write permission for a directory where the  application write some file to this directory. I read that using sandboxed application it required to [Enable Security-Scoped Bookmark and URL Access](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH3-SW16) to access a folder after relaunch the app.

So I am trying to implement it based on the code here with some minor modification [What is the correct way to handle stale NSURL bookmarks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23954662/what-is-the-correct-way-to-handle-stale-nsurl-bookmarks?rq=1)

```
     NSOpenPanel* openDlg = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
    [openDlg setCanChooseDirectories:YES];
    [openDlg setCanCreateDirectories:YES];
    [openDlg setAllowsMultipleSelection:FALSE];
    if ( [openDlg runModal] == NSOKButton )
    {
        NSArray *files = [openDlg URLs];

        NSString* dirPath =[[files objectAtIndex:0] path];// absoluteString];
        BOOL isDirectory;
        NSFileManager* manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];



        NSString *Dir = [dirPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ScreenCaptures"];
        if (![manager fileExistsAtPath:Dir isDirectory:&isDirectory] || !isDirectory)
        {
            NSError *error = nil;

            [manager createDirectoryAtPath:Dir
               withIntermediateDirectories:NO
                                attributes:nil
                                     error:&error];
            if (error)
                NSLog(@"Error creating directory snap path: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

        }


            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[Dir stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

            NSData *bookmark = nil;
            NSError *error = nil;
            bookmark = [url bookmarkDataWithOptions:NSURLBookmarkCreationWithSecurityScope
                     includingResourceValuesForKeys:nil
                                      relativeToURL:nil // Make it app-scoped
                                              error:&error];
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"Error creating bookmark for URL (%@): %@", url, error);
                [NSApp presentError:error];
            }

            NSLog(@"bookmark: %@", bookmark);
        NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [userDefaults setObject:bookmark forKey:@"bookmark"];

    }
```

But the above code giving me the error

```
016-08-20 02:19:53.390 FileAccess[635:85753] modalSession has been exited prematurely - check for a reentrant call to endModalSession:
2016-08-20 02:19:59.979 FileAccess[635:85753] Error creating bookmark for URL (/Users/development/Documents/c/ScreenCaptures): Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=262 "Scoped bookmarks can only be made with file URLs" UserInfo={NSURL=/Users/development/Documents/c/ScreenCaptures, NSDebugDescription=Scoped bookmarks can only be made with file URLs}
2016-08-20 02:20:00.021 FileAccess[635:85753] CFURLCopyResourcePropertyForKey failed because it was passed an URL which has no scheme
2016-08-20 02:20:04.967 FileAccess[635:85753] bookmark: (null)
```

What could be the problem?, anything wrong on above code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second error message tells you what is wrong - you haven't used a file:// URL.

This can be fixed by creating the URL properly from your path variable, however you will probably be better of sticking with URLs throughout and not doing the URL -> path -> URL transformation. All the operations you've used the path for can be done directly with URLs, just check the documentation for `NSFileManager` and `NSURL`. The only one which may be non-obvious is using `NSURL`'s `checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:` rather than `NSFileManager`'s `fileExistsAtPath:`, however read the documentation for `checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:` carefully and take its advice.

Making these changes should address at least three of the errors you have reported.

HTH